# Can a variable refer to a component inside of a FOR?

Tags: java, variables, for-loop

Here´s what I have:

There are 9 spell levels. The mage may cast only a certain number of spells per day.

I built a tabbed pane (9 tabs) that has 9 empty squares (images) in each tab.

The numbers below (4, 3, 2, 1 and 0s) are how many spells that the mage may cast.

I want to set the squares that won´t be used unvisible.

example:

if he can cast 4 spells on level 1, image1square5 through image1square9 become invisible.
3 spells on level 2, image2square4 through image2square9 become invisible.

I tried this:

```
int lvl1, lvl2, lvl3, lvl4, lvl5,lvl6,lvl7,lvl8,lvl9;
    lvl1 = 4 +1;
    lvl2 = 3 +1;
    lvl3 = 3 +1;
    lvl4 = 2 +1;
    lvl5 = 1 +1;
    lvl6 = 0 +1;
    lvl7 = 0 +1;
    lvl8 = 0 +1;
    lvl9 = 0 +1;

for (int i = n1; i <= 9; i++) {
            image1square+i.setVisible(false);
    }
for (int i = n2; i <= 9; i++) {
            image2square+i.setVisible(false);
    }
```

and so on...

How do I use a variable inside of a FOR?

Comment: See [this](http://arshajii.com/coding-faqs/dynamic-vars.html).

Comment: where are you declaring your `image1square` objects?

Comment: You need to look at using a `List` or an array.  Also declare and assign those variables in the same line.  `int level1 = 4+ 1;`  While we are at it `int level1 = 5;`

Answer (score 4):

Use arrays or lists instead of sequentially naming your variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a tile based game a multidimensional array or `List<List<?>>` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I went back and studied, but still won´t work. Here´s what I have now:

I omitted the

```
jImage1Empty1, jImage1Empty2, jImage2Empty1, etc,
```

but they are declared. They are jlabels with an icon on it. I have 9 images showing in each pane, but after started, it should set a few to setvisible(false).

```
int lvl[] = new int[9];
    lvl[0] = 4 +1;
    lvl[1] = 3 +1;
    lvl[2] = 3 +1;
    lvl[3] = 2 +1;
    lvl[4] = 1 +1;
    lvl[5] = 0 +1;
    lvl[6] = 0 +1;
    lvl[7] = 0 +1;
    lvl[8] = 0 +1;
    String img1 = "jImage1Empty";
    String img2 = "jImage2Empty";


    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            img1 +lvl[0].setVisible(false);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            img2 +lvl[1].setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

I wanted the result to be like:

```
jImage1Empty5.setVisible(false);
jImage1Empty6.setVisible(false);
jImage1Empty7.setVisible(false);
jImage1Empty8.setVisible(false);
jImage1Empty9.setVisible(false);
jImage2Empty4.setVisible(false);
jImage2Empty5.setVisible(false);
jImage2Empty6.setVisible(false);
jImage2Empty7.setVisible(false);
jImage2Empty8.setVisible(false);
jImage2Empty9.setVisible(false);
etc...

But not as string. As a command.
```

Is it possible? Help